# Access *View All* in Administrative Permissions in all profiles through SOQL

Tags: soql, administration, permissions, user

I want to access the field value checked/unchecked for all profiles through SOQL.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access permissions you need to use PermissionSet sobject and ProfileId field on it.

To read more about it, check [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm)

Example of soql  for your question:

```
select Profile.Name, PermissionsViewAllData FROM PermissionSet where IsOwnedByProfile = true
```

Comment: Thankyou @alexander, due to the field being categorized in administrative permissions, i got confused

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query:

```
Select Name, PermissionsViewAllUsers, PermissionsViewAllData From Profile
```